How to use the [character-motivation] tag correctly?
To give some context, I suggested to add the character-motivation tag to this question Why does the Doctor celebrate Christmas?, however the suggestion has been rejected.
I'm OK with that and I'm absolutely not questioning the decision, as several experienced users decided the tag was not adequate. However, I don't understand the reason given in the rejection votes:

This edit introduces tags that do not help to define the topic of the
question. Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not
just what it contains.

Reading the complete usage guidance of the tag ("Use this tag when asking about the motivation of a character. Character motivation is what motivates characters to behave in a particular way and describes why a particular character behaves in a specific way.", etc.), I thought it was a good, non-controversial suggestion, but obviously I was wrong.
I'd be interested in understanding the rationale for the rejection, in order to correctly use this tag in the future. I don't want to bother people with suggestions that have no chance of being approved, and I don't want to lose my time either (when I'm here to improve the website and hopefully have some fun in the process!)
I guess it might be helpful to have a couple of examples of questions that would be OK for this tag and questions where the tag would be problematic or controversial.
I'm OK with hearing that the use of this tag will always be controversial in the community (in which case, I'll simply stop suggesting adding it to questions).
Thanks!

Back in 2017, there was a consensus to abolish this and related tags, then a follow-up meta post led to a consensus to keep them. Basically, this community has always been pretty divided on tag issues.

@Randal'Thor Thanks. I was not aware of that, and it makes things much clearer.

@Randal'Thor - clear as mud, thank you.

"several experienced users decided the tag was not adequate" - to be precise, two people voted to reject and one voted to approve your suggested edit.

I didn't believe it was an improvement to the question (in my opinion), but with a bit of extra reasoning (as galacticninja says in their answer) I probably would have been persuaded to accept it. To be completely honest, I dislike those type meta tags in general, I'll keep an open mind about them if they are useful to people using and navigating the site better

@fez thanks for the feedback. I'll be much more cautious when suggesting tags now.

For future edits, try to elaborate a bit on your reasoning in the edit summary. Rather than simply stating "just adding the [character-motivation] tag," explain why the tag is appropriate. While I approved your edit—as I believe the question does indeed ask about a character's motivations—it's a bit of a gray area. A more detailed explanation in your edit summary might have swayed other reviewers.

As one of the culprits, I guess I should step up and explain my reasoning.
First, I'm somewhat conservative when it comes to tag edits; if OP tags a manga-id question with books because they believe they read it in a tankōbon, then I'll leave it even though we don't normally combine books and manga.  On the flip side, I tend not to add tags to a question unless the guidelines require it.  (Like adding star-trek to a post that only has star-trek-tng.)
So when reviewing tag edits, I'll start from an "is this required?" check and then move to "does this help?"  And pretty much I'll stop there; if it doesn't actually help, (that is, it neither helps nor hurts) then I'll reject it.
In this case I didn't feel like adding character-motivation actually helped this question.  It's asking more about an inferred pattern of behaviour rather than about a specific action that The Doctor took, and as explained in the answers it could just as easily be explained by observational bias as a choice that The Doctor made.  The edit seemed to put its thumb on the scales (as it were) of Christmas specifically being something The Doctor was doing instead of just what he happened to be doing during the stories in question.

Thanks for the explanation, +1. If it's of any interest, my own rationale for suggesting the tag was that myself, as a reader, I use the various tags on stackexchange to simply browse content, just out of curiosity. I thought that this specific tag might be helpful to people who have the same kind of use than me, as in the past I found a couple of interesting questions and answers through it (it even prompted me to ask a question a few months ago). So, so far I was rather on the "liberal" side, and it didn't cross my mind that other people could have a different philosophy toward tags.
